# Catplot returning error however boxplot does not

Tags: python, seaborn

I am having a dataset of `shape (5735,2)`

```
Sample data
  SMQ020 RIDAGEYR
0   1.0    62
1   1.0    53
2   1.0    78
3   2.0    56
4   2.0    42
```

I tried plotting with `sns.catplot(x=da.SMQ020,y=da.RIDAGEYR,data=da,kind='box')`, and it returns error as below.

However if i tried with `sns.boxplot(x=da.SMQ020,y=da.RIDAGEYR,data=da)`, it is working as intended.

I thought both of the code are identical.
Can please explain why the first code is returning this error?

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py:177: UserWarning: The left and right margins cannot be made large enough to accommodate all axes decorations. 
  warnings.warn('The left and right margins cannot be made large '
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py:182: UserWarning: The bottom and top margins cannot be made large enough to accommodate all axes decorations. 
  warnings.warn('The bottom and top margins cannot be made large '
```

Intended result (which `sns.boxplot(x=da.SMQ020,y=da.RIDAGEYR,data=da)` returns)

[image]

Comment: Are you running a recent version of seaborn? Do you really want to draw 1000s of boxes which will be impossible to visually understand? Did you try converting the `SMQ020` column to integers (`df['SMQ020'].astype(int)`)?  Note that `catplot` is a "figure level" function, so creating its own figure with subplots, while `boxplot` is an "axes level" function drawing into the "current" subplot. See [Figure-level vs. axes-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions)

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow insists on adding [code, data and error messages as text, not as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Hi Johan, i have edited the question to code. i only wanted to draw 1 box. i will read up the figure-level vs axes-level. Thanks

Comment: ok i have figureout that i have indicated the `series` in the `x` and `y` instead of the `column name` which makes the `catplot` not working. but wonder why the boxplot return the intended result

Comment: Note that Python 3.6 is rather old. Maybe you are also running an old version of Seaborn and matplotlib?

Comment: Seaborn version '0.9.0'
Matplotlib 2.2.3'

I am using website jupyter provided by Coursera.

Comment: Well, in that case it's best not to lose too much time to find out why these very old versions behave strangely.